# I cannot create a custom point in CARTO BUILDER, option is always greyed out

Tags: carto

I have recently started working with BUILDER and the option to manually add a point (either searching an address or just clicking to create) don´t work for me as with the previous interface.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Does the layer of points have any associated analysis?

Comment: Just georeference, nothing else. But, I am trying to add more points manually, and the option is not available

Answer (score 1):

If there is just one analysis attached to the layer, BUILDER is not going to leave you to add points or change the data view. There are two workarounds to add new points to your layer.

You can export the data layer, and import it again. Then, you can add points manually using [BUILDER geometry edition tool](https://carto.com/learn/guides/data-and-sql/create-and-manage-data-by-drawing-geometries). Or you can go to the original dataset and add new rows (populating the column you are using within the [Georeference analysis](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/georeference)!), then go back to the map and refresh it. The new points should show on your map.